# Is there a way to display HTML lists top-to-bottom vs left-to-right without CSS Flex?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, responsive

View: http://superdistros.com/test.html
Summary: My HTML unordered lists with list-items set to float left run left-to-right. I have used CSS Flex on the UL to display the menu items top-to-bottom so it reads Board of Directors, Capital Programs, Civil Rights top-down vs left-right.

This works well except in IE where the Flex property isn't fully compatible.

Is there another or better CSS or JS solution that can accomplish the same effect in IE 10+

I've seen similar StackOverflow Questions but not match my exact use-case. My HTML markup needs to stay the same, no adding divs, etc.

Flex CSS + https://jsfiddle.net/KevinOrin/hzro9usf/4/

```
.navbar-nav ul {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: What? HTML Unordered lists run top-to-bottom by default. It's running top-to-bottom in the link in your question too

Comment: Thanks @user1538301, I have edited my question to be more clear. If you view the url in IE you will see my list items read left-to-right. Board of Directors, Capital Programs, Civil Rights will be in first row instead of first column

Comment: "*My HTML markup needs to stay the same*" - what HTML mark-up? Your [mcve] code must be in the question, not hosted in an external resource and linked-to. An external live demo is a bonus, of course, but the relevant code must be in your question.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica, I have added a JS Fiddle. To summarize, the first 3 list-items Board of Directors, Capital Programs, Civil Rights should always run top-down in IE, not left-to-right in top row.

Answer (score 0):

This is [a bug](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-3) of flex in IE 11.

> In IE 10-11, `min-height` declarations on flex containers work to size the containers themselves, but their flex item children do not seem to know the size of their parents. They act as if no height has been set at all.

In your case, it is the same situation with `max-height`. We can solve it by adding a wrapper element around the flex container that is itself a flex container. So we make the `<div>` also flexible. You could check the sample below in full page:

```css
.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.navbar-nav li {
  padding: 0 40px 15px 0;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.navbar-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;
  /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* NEW - Chrome */
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media (min-width: 1510px) {
  .navbar-nav ul {
    max-height: 170px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1005px) and (max-width: 1509px) {
  .navbar-nav ul {
    max-height: 270px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 864px) and (max-width: 1004px) {
  .navbar-nav ul {
    max-height: 330px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav navbar-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="/department/board-directors/leadership" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/46">Board of Directors</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="/department/capital-planning/capital-programs" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/47">Capital Programs</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="/department/civil-rights/office-civil-rights" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/36">Civil Rights &amp; Diversity</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="/department/communications/communications" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/48">Communications &amp; Customer Experience</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="/department/compliance-ethics/compliance-ethics-administration" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/18414">Compliance &amp; Ethics</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="/department/finance" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/44">Finance</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="/department/human-resources/human-resources" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/32">Human Resources</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="/department/information-technology/office-information-digital-technology" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/54">Information Technology</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="/department/organizational-services/organizational-services" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/51">Organizational Services</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="/department/police/transit-police" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/37">Police</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="/department/president-ceo/president-ceo" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/18330">President &amp; CEO</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="/department/procurement/procurement-support-services" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/18371">Procurement</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="/department/rail-operations/rail-operations" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/18375">Rail Operations</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="/department/system-safety/office-system-safety" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/50">System Safety</a>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
      <a href="/department/surface-transit/surface-transit" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/45">Surface Transit</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Update：**
[This part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqUyn.png) and [this part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6ZIr.png) are the new codes, which are different from your code. Please add them to your code.

Comment: Thanks @YuZhou but I don't see any new code, your snippet is exactly the same as my code.

I did try adding a new flex div wrapper but it didn't do anything.

Comment: @KevinW. I've updated my answer, please check it. You could try to run my sample code in IE in full page mode, it works well.